# JavaCard library build with ant-javacard

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I have a **library** project & an **applet** project. Both built using **ant-javacard** just fine.

The issue I am having is when install the applet project

These are the steps:

1. The library project gets built, produces 3 things: jar, exp, and cap file
2. The applet project depends on the jar file, produces the cap file
3. After building, I install the library cap file first, then install the applet cap file

The issue occurs when installing the applet (using GlobalPlatformPro), I am getting this:

**CAP loaded
INSTALL [for install and make selectable] failed: 0x6985 (Conditions of use not satisfied)**

Any idea?

Much appreciated!

Johnny

Comment: Can you load any other applet? Did you try another card in default state with same effect? (Typically this status indicates loading failed for any reason insufficient access rights.)

Answer (score 3):

The AID-s used for testing building with ant-javacard were incorrect (overlapping) and thus rejected - rightfully - by the card. Changing the AID-s to be "correct" makes them installable. Fixing that right now.